# ALTER Stored Procedure taking forever to execute for my Bulk insert SP

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, execution-time

I am altering a stored procedure in SQL Server that I created initially but it is taking forever to execute. All other SPs behave well in the database. I am trying to do a bulk insert with this particular SP.

```
USE [HERO_G_E1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CollectData]
AS
BEGIN   
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION


        BULK INSERT TMainData
        FROM '\\MyServer\MyDbMaster\Datasets\\Data150324.txt'

        WITH
        (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
        )

        SELECT  * FROM TMainData
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),@ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),@ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

END CATCH
END
```

Comment: What is your question? How do you realistically expect anyone to provide a helpful answer to this with no knowledge of what your SP is?

Comment: Please post your SP code here.

Comment: I have posted the code now

Comment: How big is the file Data150324.txt? How many rows? If you run the `BULK INSERT` on its own how long does it take? The file probably just takes that long because it's big and you'll need to do some optimisation

Comment: The data isn't big, Just 4 rows. We had to restart the SQL Server for it to work well again. But I still don't know what really caused the problem. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed sometimes ALTER on certain objects, tends to take awhile. I don't know why(maybe someone with more knowledge of SQL Server might know). One way around it that seems to work for me at least is simply to drop the object and then recreate it. If you're not sure about all the specific characteristics of an object, you can always right click on the object and **Script Stored Procedure As>Create To> New Query Editor Window** to get yourself a good start

Example:

```
--You can preface your code so it will automatically drop it if it exists
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_CollectData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_CollectData;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_CollectData
AS
BEGIN
   /*Your Code Here*/
END;
GO
```

Comment: In my case even dropping a procedure query is taking forever, just for the knowledge of others, I will restart the server and and see the results, but I have noticed this problem which goes off after a while even If I don't do anything, and just execute the query after sometime, but today it has taken more than 30 minutes and I had to cancel the query. And I have made sure that stored procedure is not currently in use by any application, though it does not matter.